# Infinite-scroll jQuery plugin keeps populating last page

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

The problem that I am running into is that the infinitescroll plugin reaches the last valid pagination just fine then if you scroll to the bottom again, it re-pulls the last valid content.

i.e. If I have 3 valid paginated pages of content,

> page/1 = returns page 1 content
>   page/2 = returns page 2 content
>   page/3 = returns page 3 content
>   page/4 = returns page 3 content
>   page/4 = returns page 3 content
>   page/4 = returns page 3 content
>   page/4 = returns page 3 content
>   etc...
>
> If I put in page/99 it still returns page 3 content.

From looking online I need to configure the back end to return a 404 when it attempts to call a paginated page that doesn't exist.

I have 2 problems with this:

1) My client's site is hosted at SquareSpace.com (they don't give access to the 404 or very much back end at all)

2) Even if I had access, I have no idea how to fix it.

Here is a link to the article explaining that this is the issue:

https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll/issues/49

If anyone could help I would be VERY greatful!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by adding a counter to the `infinite-scroll` callback like so:

```
var total = $j(".pagination a:last").html();
var pgCount = 1;
var numPg = total;

    // jQuery InfiniteScroll Plugin.
    container.infinitescroll({
        navSelector  : '.pagination',
        nextSelector : '.pagination a:first',
        itemSelector : '.journal-entry-wrapper',
        animate: true,
        loading: {
            finishedMsg: 'No more content to load.',
            img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
        }
    },
    // Trigger Masonry as a callback.
    function( newElements ) {
        pgCount++;

        if(pgCount == numPg) {
            $j(window).unbind('.infscr');
            container.masonry('reload');
            container.append( newElements ).masonry( 'appended', newElements, true );
            $j('#infscr-loading').find('em').text('No more content to load.');
            $j('#infscr-loading').animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 200);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $j('#infscr-loading').animate({
                    opacity: 0
                }, 300);
            });
        } else {
            loadPosts(newElements);
        }
    }); 

});

function loadPosts(newElements) {
    // Hide new posts while they are still loading.
    var newElems = $j( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
    // Ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout.
    newElems.imagesLoaded(function() {
        // Show new elements now that they're loaded.
        newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
        container.masonry( 'appended', newElems, true );

        // Animate opaque post covers on hover.
        $j(newElems).hover(function() {
            $j(this).find('.postCover').stop(true, true).fadeOut(200);
        }, function() {
            $j(this).find('.postCover').stop(true, true).fadeIn(200);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Hope this helps someone else. Just for informational this was for a client who was hosting with SquareSpace.